# C# MethodInvoker vs Action

Tags: c#, делегаты

В чем разница, если она существует (в теории и на практике), между делегатами MethodInvoker и Action ?

Comment: `MethodInvoker` - специальный делегат, который используется в WinForms. `Action` - универсальный делегат .NET. Если речь не идет о WinForms (или о WPF), то стоит использовать исключительно `Action`

Comment: `MethodInvoker` появился в FW1.1, ещё до введения дженериков. С их появлением стало возможно сделать обобщённый `Action`. Если бы дженерики были изначально, то надобности в `MethodInvoker` не было бы.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, MethodInvoker и Action - это всего лишь сигнатуры, описания. Фактически они взаимозаменяемые и можно один тип свободно приводить к другому. Ну и как сказали выше, так просто исторически сложилось, что MethodInvoker был в самом начале, а потом добавили Action обычный и дженерик. Точно не скажу, но скорее всего ради удобства, потому что MethodInvoker писать в коде по многу раз задолбаешься, в отличии от обычных Action и его "брата" Func.